# How branchout is doing notifications?

Tags: php, javascript, facebook-graph-api

Yesterday BranchOut notifies me that a friend has joined to this app in top bar, and ask me if  I want to receive notifications from Branchout.

If I understand well there are two kind of notifications:
- user to user: that appears in top bar
- app to user: appears in app left bar

So, my question is... anyone knows how they are doing that?

thanks!

[image: printscreen]

this is exactly the message that BranchOut shows me

Answer (score 0):

It could be one of two reasons:

BranchOut has access to exclusive notification features from Facebook.

Facebook is promoting apps that have been recently installed by Friends. In this case, because a friend installed the BranchOut application.

Comment: Hi @niraj-shah , both options can be but in my opinion I don't think so. It's strange... the notification seems like an app to user notification but with the logic of "user to user notifications". thanks!

Comment: Try using a app-generated `access_token` to send a request and see if you can mimic what BranchOut does.

Comment: probably @nathan-smith ( http://stackoverflow.com/users/505252/nathan-smith ) can help us

Comment: http://www.insidefacebook.com/2012/06/11/facebook-tries-promoting-games-with-notifications/